# Finding base vectors for subspace and extending to full space

Tags: linear-algebra

**The problem:**

The set of all vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ that satisfy the equation:

$x_1-3x_2+2x_3+4x_4=0$

Form a subspace $L$ to $R^4$ which has the dimension $3$. Make a base vector $e_1,e_2,e_3$ for $L$. Further, make a fourth vector $e_4$ which together with $e_1, e_2, e_3$ becomes a base for $R^4$.

**what I've come up with:**

My train of thought is that we could simply take out one vector from the equation and then try to find another one which:

1. Is orthogonal to the first vector
2. Satisfies the equation

This turned out to be unfruitful because I am not sure how to satisfy both predicates in a useful way.

When it comes to the second part of the problem (finding $e_4$) then I thought that we could just take the vector $(1, -3, 2, 4)$. This should form the normal vector to $L$, right?

Comment: You're missing the equation--looks like you only gave the left-hand side of it.

Comment: D'oh, silly me. Added :)

Comment: Also, about your general solution, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "take out one vector from the equation".  I would solve for one vector, produce a parameterized solution that exhibits a basis.  Your method of finding $e_{4}$ is perfect, though.

Comment: "take out one vector from the equation" = solve for one vector. Sorry for not being clear about that.

How exactly would you produce a "parameterized solution that exhibits a basis"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not totally clear on what you have in mind for a solution method, but I'll produce what I'd do:

Solve for one variable (not sure what you mean by "solve for a vector" unless you mean this, or just pick numbers to satisfy the equation):

$x_{1} = 3x_{2}-2x_{3}-4x_{4}$

Now express this as a vector equation for $\left[ \begin{matrix} x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4}\end{matrix}\right]$.  That is to say, write this vector on the left of an =, and write an expression on the right which contains only the parameters $x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$.  Like so.

$\left[ \begin{matrix} x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4}\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}3x_{2}-2x_{3}-4x_{4}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4}\end{matrix}\right]$

and this, separating parameters out, is

$= x_{2}\left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right] + x_{3}\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\\0 \end{matrix}\right] + x_{4}\left[\begin{matrix}-4\\0\\0\\1 \end{matrix}\right] $

so a basis is

$\left\{ \left[\begin{matrix}3\\1\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}-2\\0\\1\\0 \end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}-4\\0\\0\\1 \end{matrix}\right]\right\}$